# Send image from main PC to other PCs in same network

Tags: networking, display, slideshow

I search for a way to send **what will be displayed** to many PCs monitors from a main PC.

Basically, I have a main PC and other 6 PCs in the same network but in different floors.

That I want, is to control from the main PC what are showed on the others. Every other PC have to show a number of tabs in a browser which will be slideshow using a chrome plugin.

In other words, I want to be able to send different screen to every PC but to be controled by a main PC. (I found a software named MonitorsAnywhere that does what I exactly want, however it needs to have HDMI over LAN zero-clients)

I don't want to pay for extra hardware as I already have a PC connected to every monitor.

Comment: Do you want all 6x remote PCs to show what the "_main_" PC has on it's screen? Or do you want to be able to remotely control the 6x remote PCs _from_ the "_main_" PC?

Comment: I want to be able to send different screen to every PC but to be controled by a main PC. Thanks! (I found a software named MonitorsAnywhere that does what I exactly want, however it needs to have HDMI over LAN zero-clients)

Comment: Why not use VNC or similar?

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information, don't put it in the comments (I did it for you now, next time you do it). Also, please add an OS tag (Windows? Mac? Linux?).

Answer (score 0):

I am little confused about your description. Please check my understanding whether it is right.

1.What are the six PCs? Are they personal computer or monitors?
2.Do you want to control another six PCs by a main PC?
In my humble opinion, if they are six monitors, you need to obtain graphics to realize multi-screen output.
This link maybe helpful for you.
*https://www.pcworld.com/article/2923941/displays/how-to-create-an-insane-multiple-monitor-setup-with-three-four-or-more-displays.html*

If they are six PCs(personal computer), you can use RDP to realize your requests.
Following are steps:

1.On the main PC, press **'win+R'** on your keyboard and type in **'mstsc'**
[image]

2.Type the computer's IP address that you want to control.
[image]

3.Click on **connect** and you need an authentication,then you can control this PC.

4.You can minimize the remote desktop windows and do the steps above again to control more PCs.

Have a nice day,

Peter